# Regular Expression - replace urls in style tags

Tags: css, regex, stylesheet

I have searched on google and stackoverflow but didnt find a good answer. I also tryed it by myself, but iam no regex guru.

My goal is to replace all relative urls in a html style tag with the absolute version.

e.g.

- `style="url(/test.png)"` with `style="url(http://mysite.com/test.png)"`
- `style="url("/test.png")"` with `style="url("http://mysite.com/test.png")"`
- `style="url('/test.png')"` with `style="url('http://mysite.com/test.png')"`
- `style="url(../test.png)"` with `style="url(http://mysite.com/test.png)"`
- `style="url("../test.png")"` with `style="url('http://mysite.com/test.png')"`
- `style="url('../test.png')"` with `style="url('http://mysite.com/test.png')"`

and so on.

Here what i tryed with my poor regex "skils"

```
url\((?<Url>[^\)]*)\)
```

gives me the url in the "url" function.

thanks in advance!

Comment: *I also tryed it by myself*, please share that.. You've 20K^, we can expect this from you

Comment: :) you are right. I extend my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can try the regex:

```
style="url\((['"])?(?:\.\.)?(?<url>[^'"]+)\1?\)"
```

And replace with:

```
style="url($1http://mysite.com$2$1)"
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/pP6kS6)

`(['"])?` will capture quotes if they are present and use them again at `\1?`

`([^'"]+)` will capture the url itself.